# How to convert normal array into an associative array using php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a string this one: `position1, position2`

Basically i want to have this kind of structure -

`array(
    array('position' => 'position 1'),
    array('position' => 'position 2')
)`

i have tried this so far.

```
$positions = explode(',', "position1, position2");

    $modPoses = [];

    foreach($positions as $pose):
        $modPoses['position'] = $pose;
    endforeach;

    print_r($modPoses);
```

`Output:`

```
Array ( [position] => position2 )
```

How can i get desired(mentioned above) array structure? 
Thank you.

Comment: `['position'=>'position1', 'position'=>'position2']` <-- this doesn't make any sense

Comment: i want to convert it into javascript object later. Thats why i need this kind of structure) .

Comment: _i want to convert it into javascript object later..._ maybe we are talking about a XY-problem... as said before it does NOT make any sense having an array with same keys and different values...not sure even if this is valid

Comment: PHP array cannot contain the same key twice. What would You expect `$array['position']` to return?

Comment: i want to make structure like js object (array of objects). for example: `[{position:position1},{'position:position2}]`  is it posible using php and convert it into Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that what You want is:

```
array(
    array('position' => 'position 1'),
    array('position' => 'position 2')
)
```

If that is so, You can use:

```
array_map(function ($i) { return array('position' => $i); }, explode(',', 'position 1, position 2'))
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any sense that you assign two values to same index but let me give you a solution. If you use 2d associative array then you can do it in this way

```
$counter = 0; //initialize counter here
foreach($positions as $pose):
        $modPoses[$counter]['position'] = $pose;
        $counter++;
     endforeach;
```

Comment: `foreach($positions as $pose) { $modPoses[]['position'] = $pose; }`

Comment: @splash58 multiple ways